# disable or hide iPad 2x button

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is there any way to disable the 2x button for an iPhone application running on iPad? Or the other way round, is there a possibility to run the iPad app in 2x mode always disabling 1x mode?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it involves converting the app into a universal binary and building an iPad interface. The iPad is not a niche market anymore, developers should be building for both iPhone and iPad now. No excuses.

Answer (score 3):

Only by implementing a universal app, i.e., one that natively supports iPhone and iPad. If the 2x mode works okay -- I hesitate to say well -- it shouldn't be *that* hard to do.